# Why QKeyPress event don't work without window?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

if i add this function:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QKeyEvent:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or Qt.Key_1:
                print('Key was pressed')
```

to this code :

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

class Frame:
    def __init__(self, position, time):
        self.position = position
        self.time = time

    def speed(self, frame):
        d = distance(*self.position, *frame.position)
        time_delta = abs(frame.time - self.time)
        return d / time_delta

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.last_frame = None
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        nowTime = datetime.now()
        mouseWasMoveAt = nowTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

        new_frame = Frame((event.x(), event.y()), time.time())

        if self.last_frame:
            print(new_frame.speed(self.last_frame), mouseWasMoveAt ) #print speed and time

        self.last_frame = new_frame

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QKeyEvent:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or Qt.Key_1:
                print('Key was pressed')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(900,600)
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

everything works fine, but this KeyPressevent works only if i have a window, but i no need a window, i want that keyboard event will handled without it. I try to do like this:

```
class Frame:
    def __init__(self, position, time):
        self.position = position
        self.time = time


    def speed(self, frame):
        d = distance(*self.position, *frame.position)
        time_delta = abs(frame.time - self.time)
        return d / time_delta

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if type(event) == QKeyEvent:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or Qt.Key_1:
                print('Key was pressed')

def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)

def get_current_cursor_position():
    pos = QCursor.pos()
    return pos.x(), pos.y()

def get_current_frame():
    return Frame(get_current_cursor_position(), time.time())



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    last_frame = get_current_frame()


    while True:
        nowTime = datetime.now()
        mouseWasMoveAt = nowTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        new_frame = get_current_frame()

        if new_frame.speed(last_frame) != 0:

            print(mouseWasMoveAt)
            last_frame = new_frame
            time.sleep(0.07)
```

This code don't work, what i should to do? 
And another question is:
if i write my keyEvent func like this

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
       if type(event) == QKeyEvent:
           if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or Qt.Key_1:
               print('Key was pressed')
```

print() will print me any key that i press, but if i change if statement to if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 print() will print only Key_0 button. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your working code `keyPressEvent` is a member of `MainWindow` which, in turn, inherits from `QMainWindow`.  Because of the inheritance the `Qt` framework knows how to dispatch events to instances of `MainWindow` and so `keyPressEvent` will be invoked as expected.

In the code that fails `Frame` doesn't inherit in any way from `QWidget` (or anything for that matter).  As such, any instance of `Frame` is essentially independent of `Qt` and, hence, no events will be posted to it.

Regarding your second question...

> if i change if statement to if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 print() will
>   print only Key_0 button. Why is this happening?

Rather than...

```
if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or Qt.Key_1:
```

you probably want...

```
if event.key() == Qt.Key_0 or event.key() == Qt.Key_1:
```

If what you want is a console application that uses keyboard input rather than a full blown GUI you might want to look at [python curses](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html).

Comment: Thanks! Already done my task with handling keyboard event using this lib https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard